# How to get a product from woocommerce using custom meta value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to get specific product using meta key value. Any help would be highly appreciated.
I am trying to display a specific product when the product code is passed via a shortcode.

I have setup metabox and confirmed that the items have custom meta values with key "neproductinfo-ne_item_code"

```php
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'itemcode'  => '',
            ),
            $atts, 'products_catalog'
        );


        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = 1;

        $meta_query_args = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'neproductinfo-ne_item_code',
                'value' => $atts['itemcode'],
                'compare'   => '='
            )
        );
        $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );  


        $products = new WP_Query( array (
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            //'posts_per_page'    => 1,
            'meta_query'        => $meta_query
        ));
```

I am getting list of all products regardless of any itemcode passed through shortcode

shortcode example
[products_catalog itemcode='1001']

Answer (score 0):

No if condition found where you are checking the attribute value exists or not.
Based on existence of attribute value, you need to pass meta query. If there is no value then y you passs the `meta_query` to WP_Query ?

Comment: I have confirmed that every value exists for the meta key. all products hav meta key "neproductinfo-ne_item_code" and a value

Comment: You are not getting what i mean. When this value `$atts['itemcode']` is not empty then only you need to execute meta query. Have you checked the condition that the value is not empty?